# SQL find distinct values with same id

Tags: sql, select

Hi I am trying to find duplicates with the same ID.   I am not finding all of the duplicates.  I would like to find distinct JOIN_FID values, and then duplicate JOIN FID values.

Here is my SQL select statements.

```
select  OBJECTID,
    Join_Count,
    TARGET_FID,
    JOIN_FID,
    StrtConcat,
    PermID,
    Minutes,
    FacilityID,
    Shape
from 
    sde.gis.MFD_8_minute_response_ladder
where TARGET_FID
    in (
select
    JOIN_FID
from
    sde.gis.MFD_8_minute_response_ladder
group by
    JOIN_FID
having 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: ...and what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing parenthesis (`)`), but I assume that's a typo.

I suspect the problem may be that you're comparing two different fields:

```
where TARGET_FID
    in (
select
    JOIN_FID
```

Should that be:

```
where TARGET_FID
    in (
select
    TARGET_FID
```

or

```
where JOIN_FID
    in (
select
    JOIN_FID
```

?

For the query that you added ,an IN subquery can only return one value, so you need something like:

```
where PermID
    in (
select
    COUNT(1),
    TARGET_FID
```

making sure you're comparing the right columns.